# How to keep dates as index and inner join keys in multiple excel files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate different excel files - same columns, each file comes from a different category - using the date (as an index) from the first file.

The excel file format is basically a Date column (19.09.2014) and other columns with float.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import os
import seaborn as sns

country = ["Brazil", "Chile", "Colombia"]

    PD = pd.read_excel("Brazil.xls", parse_dates = True , format = '%dd%.mm.%YYYY', index_col = [0], skiprows=1 )
    PD = pd.DataFrame( PD[str("Ann.PD-" + rec)]) 
    PD.columns = ['Brazil']
    print(PD.head())
```

Once I am interested in just one of the column from the files, the output is the following:

```
    Brazil
Date              
2014-09-19     2.2
2014-09-22     2.5
2014-09-23     2.4
2014-09-24     2.4
2014-09-25     2.5
```

From now on, I want to use the dates of this first country file (Brazil) as the date for reference to join with the other files. Therefore, I need to iterate through other files for the remaining countries in the list. The iteration is the following:

```
for ct in country[1:]:
    b = pd.read_excel(str(ct + ".xls"), parse_dates = True, format = '%dd%.mm.%YYYY', index_col = [0], skiprows=1,)
    b = pd.DataFrame(b[ str("Ann.PD-" + rec) ] )
    b.columns = [ct]
    PD = pd.concat([PD, b], axis = 1 )
print(PD.head(3))

            Brazil  Chile  Colombia  Mexico  Panama  Peru  Venezuela
Date                                                                
2014-01-10     2.7    1.3       1.6     1.4     1.6   1.7       15.3
2014-01-12     2.5    1.2       1.7     1.4     1.5   1.7       18.3
2014-02-10     2.7    1.3       1.6     1.4     1.5   1.7       15.4
```

As you can see, the dates change, although all the files have the same ones. Anyone knows how to keep the dates being both an index and a key for the inner join ?

I expected to have the following output:

```
            Brazil  Chile  Colombia  Mexico  Panama  Peru  Venezuela
Date                                                                
2014-09-19     2.7    1.3       1.6     1.4     1.6   1.7       15.3
2014-09-22     2.5    1.2       1.7     1.4     1.5   1.7       18.3
2014-09-23     2.7    1.3       1.6     1.4     1.5   1.7       15.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having an example dataframes, it is hard to determine the issue but I presume that the `pd.concat` operation overrides the index.

You should usually read all of the files in and then concatenate them, that's faster and more efficient (described in pd.concat [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)) when using `pd.concat`

#### Try this

Read all of the excel files into a dictionary:

```
dat_dict = {}

for ct in country:
    b = pd.read_excel(str(ct + ".xls"), parse_dates = True, format = '%dd%.mm.%YYYY', index_col = [0], skiprows=1,)

    #I am not sure what b is but if you can store it as a pd.Series in the data_dict
    #instead of pd.Dataframe then you won't need b.iloc[:,0] later on.

    b = pd.DataFrame(b[ str("Ann.PD-" + rec) ] )
    #b.columns = [ct]
    dat_dict[ct] = b.iloc[:,0]
```

then concatenate them:

```
stacked_df = pd.concat(dat_dict)
```

`stacked_df` should be a multi-leveled dataframe with countries in level 0 and dates in level 1. Thus, you can use the `unstack` operation to get the desired output.

```
df = stack_df.unstack(level=0)
```

#### Consider the example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2014-09-19', '2014-09-22'], 'Brazil':[2.7, 2.2]})
df1.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df1.Date), inplace=True); df1.drop('Date', inplace=True, axis=1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2014-10-30', '2014-11-05'], 'Chile':[1.3, 1.2]})
df2.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df2.Date), inplace=True); df2.drop('Date', inplace=True, axis=1)

df_stacked = pd.concat({'brazil':df1.iloc[:,0],'chile':df2.iloc[:,0]}, axis=0)
```

unstacking the above gives

```
In [39]: df_stacked.unstack(level=0)
Out[39]:
            brazil  chile
Date
2014-09-19     2.7    NaN
2014-09-22     2.2    NaN
2014-10-30     NaN    1.3
2014-11-05     NaN    1.2
```

Comment: Thanks Gene. This is really helpful! Did not know anything about the multi-leveled dataframe. It seems a little odd at first time, but it turns out to be very handy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `pd.concat` on a list compression where I apply the file parsing via a function and pass the `keys` parameter to get the proper column headings.

```
def get_df(ct):
    fn = str(ct) + ".xls"
    kw = dict(parse_dates=True,
              format='%dd%.mm.%YYYY',
              index_col=[0], skiprows=1)
    b = pd.read_excel(fn, **kw)
    # I don't know what 'rec' is.
    # I left it in but you'll have to deal with it.
    return b[str("Ann.PD-" + rec)]
    return b

pd.concat([get_df(ct) for ct in country], axis=1, keys=country)
```

I can't validate this at the moment

Comment: Sorry abouto the Rec, my fault. Rec is a string, "40 %" for instance so I can select the different columns from those excel files according to the chosen Rec.